# Error converting data type float to datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to convert the data type float below to datetime format:

> df

```
         Date
0         NaN
1         NaN
2    201708.0
4    201709.0
5    201700.0
6    201600.0
Name: Cred_Act_LstPostDt_U324123, dtype: float64
```

> pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%Y%m.0')

ValueError: time data 201700.0 does not match format '%Y%m.0' (match)

How could I transform these rows without month information as yyyy01 as default?

Comment: Create a var that contains the float as a string, then split the string at the fourth char and insert a hypen. Then you can use format='%Y%m'

Comment: that's because there's no such thing as month '0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to clean up your month data:

```
s = [x.replace('00.0', '01.0') for x in df['Date'].astype(str)]
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%Y%m.0', errors='coerce')

print(df)

        Date
0        NaT
1        NaT
2 2017-08-01
4 2017-09-01
5 2017-01-01
6 2016-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a string that contains the float using .asType(str), then split the string at the fourth char and using cat insert a hyphen. Then you can use format='%Y%m.

However this may still fail if you try to use incorrect month numbering, such as month 00

```
string = df['Date'].astype(str)
s = pd.Series([string[:4], '-',string[4:6])
date = s.str.cat(sep=',')
pd.to_datetime(date.astype(str),format='%Y%m')
```

Comment: Any, thanks, but I got the error message: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Series found

Comment: My bad, I forgot to convert the Series back to string. I updated the code snippet